# dealing with huge number of rows (pandas dataframe) to filter rows on condition

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I have a large dataset with 171534 rows of purchases basket. In the process of calculating the similarities between the products that the dataset contains ( 84088 unique product), I wanted to filter on only products that were purchased more than once (31878 products).

So here what I did:

```
grouped_by_product = df_temp.groupby("basket")["event_data"].aggregate({'orders': 'count'}).reset_index()

grouped_by_product = grouped_by_product[grouped_by_product['orders'] > 1]

products_list = grouped_by_product['basket'].tolist()
#filter df_temp on only  rows that contain a product purchased more than once
f_temp= df_temp[df_temp['basket'].isin(products_list)]
```

The last line takes a lot of time to be finished. Is there a better way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'event_data':[5,3,6,9,2,4,7],
                        'basket':list('abbbccd')})

print (df_temp)
   event_data basket
0           5      a
1           3      b
2           6      b
3           9      b
4           2      c
5           4      c
6           7      d
```

General solution for filtering by `count` is [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return same `Series` of aggregate values with same size as original `df`:

```
df = df_temp[df_temp.groupby("basket")["event_data"].transform('count') > 1]
print (df)
   event_data basket
1           3      b
2           6      b
3           9      b
4           2      c
5           4      c
```

Fuplicated rows by `basket` column use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with parameter `kep=False` for return all dupes:

```
df = df_temp[df_temp.duplicated("basket", keep=False)]
print (df)
   event_data basket
1           3      b
2           6      b
3           9      b
4           2      c
5           4      c
```